# Azure Active Directory App Registration works for me but no one else in organization

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-appservice

I have an AAD app registration.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

i have an asp.net core app deployed to a windows app service on azure.
I followed this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core&tabs=windows

```
static WebApplicationBuilder ConfigureAuthentication(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
            {
                builder.Configuration.AddInMemoryCollection(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AzureAd:ClientSecret", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"))
            });
            }
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(builder.Configuration.GetScopes())
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
            builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnTokenValidated += HandleValidAuth;
                options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed += HandleFailedAuth;
                options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived += async ctx => { };
            });
            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(bldr => 
            bldr.AddPolicy(
                name: "MalibuDevs", 
                configurePolicy: x => 
                    x.RequireClaim(
                        claimType: "groups",
                        allowedValues: "[[redacted]]")));
            return builder;
        }
```

```
[RequireHttps(Order = 0)]
    [Authorize("MalibuDevs")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    { ... }
```

I can open the app, use SSO and log in and use group access (I added group access tokens to the app registration). redirect URLs work on app registration.

Bottom line, I can log in but no one else in org can log in.

I'm not even sure how I would troubleshoot this.